# Error when I try to predict class probabilities in R - caret

Tags: r, predict, r-caret

I've build a model using caret. When the training was completed I got the following warning:

**Warning message:
In train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) :
  At least one of the class levels are not valid R variables names; This may cause errors if class probabilities are generated because the variables names will be converted to: X0, X1**

The names of the variables are:

```
      str(train)
'data.frame':   7395 obs. of  30 variables:
 $ alchemy_category              : Factor w/ 13 levels "arts_entertainment",..: 2 8 6 6 11 6 1 6 3 8 ...
 $ alchemy_category_score        : num  3737 2052 4801 3816 3179 ...
 $ avglinksize                   : num  2.06 3.68 2.38 1.54 2.68 ...
 $ commonlinkratio_1             : num  0.676 0.508 0.562 0.4 0.5 ...
 $ commonlinkratio_2             : num  0.206 0.289 0.322 0.1 0.222 ...
 $ commonlinkratio_3             : num  0.0471 0.2139 0.1202 0.0167 0.1235 ...
 $ commonlinkratio_4             : num  0.0235 0.1444 0.0426 0 0.0432 ...
 $ compression_ratio             : num  0.444 0.469 0.525 0.481 0.446 ...
 $ embed_ratio                   : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ frameTagRatio                 : num  0.0908 0.0987 0.0724 0.0959 0.0249 ...
 $ hasDomainLink                 : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ html_ratio                    : num  0.246 0.203 0.226 0.266 0.229 ...
 $ image_ratio                   : num  0.00388 0.08865 0.12054 0.03534 0.05047 ...
 $ is_news                       : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 1 2 1 ...
 $ lengthyLinkDomain             : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 ...
 $ linkwordscore                 : num  24 40 55 24 14 12 21 5 17 14 ...
 $ news_front_page               : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ non_markup_alphanum_characters: num  5424 4973 2240 2737 12032 ...
 $ numberOfLinks                 : num  170 187 258 120 162 55 93 132 194 326 ...
 $ numwords_in_url               : num  8 9 11 5 10 3 3 4 7 4 ...
 $ parametrizedLinkRatio         : num  0.1529 0.1818 0.1667 0.0417 0.0988 ...
 $ spelling_errors_ratio         : num  0.0791 0.1254 0.0576 0.1009 0.0826 ...
 $ label                         : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 2 2 ...
 $ isVideo                       : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 ...
 $ isFashion                     : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 ...
 $ isFood                        : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ hasComments                   : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 ...
 $ hasGoogleAnalytics            : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 2 2 1 ...
 $ hasInlineCSS                  : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 2 2 ...
 $ noOfMetaTags                  : num  10 12 6 10 13 2 6 6 9 5 ...
```

My code is the following:

```
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "CV",
                     number=10,
                     classProbs = TRUE,
                     allowParallel = TRUE,
                     summaryFunction = twoClassSummary)

set.seed(476)
rfFit <- train(formula,
               data=train,
               method = "rf",
               tuneGrid = expand.grid(.mtry = seq(4,20,by=2)),
               ntrees=1000,
               importance = TRUE,
               metric = "ROC",
               trControl = ctrl)


pred <- predict.train(rfFit, newdata = test, type = "prob")
```

I get the error: **Error in `[.data.frame`(out, , obsLevels, drop = FALSE) : 
  undefined columns selected**

The variable names on the test data set are:

```
str(test)
'data.frame':   3171 obs. of  29 variables:
 $ alchemy_category              : Factor w/ 13 levels "arts_entertainment",..: 8 4 12 4 10 12 12 8 1 2 ...
 $ alchemy_category_score        : num  5307 4825 1 6708 5416 ...
 $ avglinksize                   : num  2.56 3.77 2.27 2.52 1.85 ...
 $ commonlinkratio_1             : num  0.39 0.462 0.496 0.706 0.471 ...
 $ commonlinkratio_2             : num  0.257 0.205 0.385 0.346 0.161 ...
 $ commonlinkratio_3             : num  0.0441 0.0513 0.1709 0.123 0.0323 ...
 $ commonlinkratio_4             : num  0.0221 0 0.1709 0.0906 0 ...
 $ compression_ratio             : num  0.49 0.782 1.25 0.449 0.454 ...
 $ embed_ratio                   : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ frameTagRatio                 : num  0.0671 0.0429 0.0588 0.0581 0.093 ...
 $ hasDomainLink                 : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ html_ratio                    : num  0.23 0.366 0.162 0.147 0.244 ...
 $ image_ratio                   : num  0.19944 0.08 10 0.00596 0.03571 ...
 $ is_news                       : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 ...
 $ lengthyLinkDomain             : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 1 1 1 ...
 $ linkwordscore                 : num  15 62 42 41 34 35 15 22 41 7 ...
 $ news_front_page               : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ non_markup_alphanum_characters: num  5643 382 2420 5559 2209 ...
 $ numberOfLinks                 : num  136 39 117 309 155 266 55 145 110 1 ...
 $ numwords_in_url               : num  3 2 1 10 10 7 1 9 5 0 ...
 $ parametrizedLinkRatio         : num  0.2426 0.1282 0.5812 0.0388 0.0968 ...
 $ spelling_errors_ratio         : num  0.0806 0.1765 0.125 0.0631 0.0653 ...
 $ isVideo                       : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 2 1 2 2 2 1 1 2 2 ...
 $ isFashion                     : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ isFood                        : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ hasComments                   : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 1 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 1 ...
 $ hasGoogleAnalytics            : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 ...
 $ hasInlineCSS                  : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 ...
 $ noOfMetaTags                  : num  3 6 5 9 16 22 6 9 7 0 ...
```

If I omit the type="prob" part, I get no error.

Any ideas?

Could it be the length of the variable "alchemy_category" which is appended with the respective factor levels e.g. "alchemy_categoryarts_entertainment" inside the model??

Comment: It's not the length of these variables. I shortened them but the problem remains..

Comment: I removed all factors (except the response variable of course) and I keep getting the same error!!

Comment: Set `classProbs = FALSE` in `trainControl`

Answer (score 42):

The answer is in bold at the top of your post =]

What are you modeling? Is it `alchemy_category`? The code only says `formula` and we can't see it.

When you ask for class probabilities, model predictions are a data frame with separate columns for each class/level. If `alchemy_category` doesn't have levels that are valid column names, `data.frame` converts then to valid names. That creates a problem because the code is looking for a specific name but the data frame as a different (but valid) name.

For example, if I had

```
> test <- factor(c("level1", "level 2")) 
> levels(test)
[1] "level 2" "level1" 
> make.names(levels(test))
[1] "level.2" "level1"
```

the code would be looking for "level 2" but there is only "level.2".

Comment: Sorry I've not included here my formula. I model the 'label', therefore "0" or "1". 

What do you mean that "the answer is in bold at the top of my post =]"?? I don't get it.

Comment: @Stergios  He means that the warning message that you included explains what is going wrong.  Since "0" and "1" are not valid R variable names, you get errors when generating class probabilities.

Comment: Good Explanation. I had my classes as 0 and 1 and it kept failing due to the above error message. Changing those to "No" and "Yes" fixed the issue.

Comment: and if you predict a logical outcome, note that `TRUE` and `FALSE` are not acceptable column names.

Comment: In my case,  the solution was to remove the **spaces** in the factor *levels*. I mean, before converting the *char* column to *factor*, I did something like: `train_b <- train_a %>% 
  mutate(state=recode(state,'Fully Paid'='FullyPaid'))`

Answer (score 17):

As stated above the class values must be factors and must be valid names. Another way to insure this is,

```
levels(all.dat$target) <- make.names(levels(factor(all.dat$target)))
```

Comment: Does this preserve the dataset? Because I used this line of code and my "y" variable is now of factor form X0 and X1 with outcomes 0 and 1.

Answer (score 10):

I have read through the answers above while facing a similar problem. A formal solution is to do this on the train and test datasets. Make sure you include the response variable in the feature.names too.

```
feature.names=names(train)

for (f in feature.names) {
  if (class(train[[f]])=="factor") {
    levels <- unique(c(train[[f]]))
    train[[f]] <- factor(train[[f]],
                   labels=make.names(levels))
  }
}
```

This creates syntactically correct labels for all factors.

Answer (score 1):

As @Sam Firke already pointed out in comments (but I overlooked it) levels TRUE/FALSE also don't work. So I converted them to yes/no.

Answer (score 0):

As per the above example, usually refactoring the outcome variable will fix the problem. It's better to change in the original dataset before partitioning into training and test datasets

levels <- unique(data$outcome)
data$outcome <- factor(data$outcome, labels=make.names(levels))

As others pointed out earlier, this problem only occurs when classProbs=TRUE which causes the train function to generate additional statistics related to the outcome class